# Show suggestions for textbox in PowerApp

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Is it possible to show suggestions when typing text for a textbox in Powerapps?

We need user to be able to enter anything in a textbox, also new values, but should be guided to use a pre-existing value if applicable. We will probably have more than a thousand different values.

Comment: My need was to also insert new values and for that the solution is not working. It only allows you to select from values already in the datasource.

Comment: I missed that. btw great idea, you can build that component & share it to community. I also need that :)

Answer (score 0):

We call this as type ahead or autocomplete control, the same point was added as an idea in PowerApps feedback page [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/Autocomplete-control/idi-p/1474). The solution recommended by Microsoft was to use [Combo box control in PowerApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-combo-box).